# resultSet.next() always false

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am debugging this code:

```
try {
    DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
    try ( ResultSet resultSet = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, TABLE.toLowerCase(), column.toLowerCase()))
    {
        return resultSet.next();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    logger.error(e);
    return false;
}
```

In debug, `databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, TABLE.toLowerCase(), column.toLowerCase()).next()` gives true, however, `resultSet.next()` is always giving false!

Comment: `if (resultSet.next() return true; return false;` can be more easily debugged.

Comment: Which database system are you using? A lot of database systems store the case-insensitive (unquoted) table and column names in uppercase.

Comment: this error happens only for postgres, with sybase it works fine.
note that I added the `.toLowerCase` to get the expression true so after adding `.toLowerCase`, databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, TABLE.toLowerCase(), column.toLowerCase()).next() returns true, but then the  resultSet.next() returns false

Comment: @JoopEggen didn't get your point

Comment: @MarkRotteveel clear ?

Comment: A new attack. Connect and disconnect the connection in the same method. I still would do something like a `while (resultSet.next()) { logger.info("Boo"); } logger.info("Done"); return ...;` Which is pure paranoia. TABLE an other constant.

Comment: `try (ResultSet resultSet = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, TABLE.toLowerCase(), column.toLowerCase()))
            {
                logger.info("start");
                while (resultSet.next()) { logger.info("Boo"); } logger.info("Done");
                return resultSet.next();
            }`
I added this, start was NOT printed, it's weird ! @JoopEggen

Comment: Maybe `logger.error` is reached and logs to nirwana. Or log level info of start is not shown. Debugging...